# Saving Each Iteration of DataFrame "for loop" results as a new array in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I need to save each iteration results as a new list or Dataframe. I can print the results. But I need to use them in another step of my work. I need each array saved in project.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame()
m =np.random.randint(1, 30, size = (10, 3))
df = pd.DataFrame(m, columns = ["var1", "var2", "var3"])
for i in range(0, len(df)+1):
        for j in range(0, len(df)+1):
            if i-j==3:
                b = df.iloc[j:i]
                print(b)
```

Output

```
var1  var2  var3
0    12     1    26
1     2     2    20
2     2     8     1
   var1  var2  var3
1     2     2    20
2     2     8     1
3     2     5    26
   var1  var2  var3
2     2     8     1
3     2     5    26
4    18    19    23
   var1  var2  var3
3     2     5    26
4    18    19    23
5    10    18    17
   var1  var2  var3
4    18    19    23
5    10    18    17
6    14     2    16
   var1  var2  var3
5    10    18    17
6    14     2    16
7    15    19    23
   var1  var2  var3
6    14     2    16
7    15    19    23
8     6    27     8
   var1  var2  var3
7    15    19    23
8     6    27     8
9    11     1    11
```

When I try to save them into new array, I tried to add this code below;

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame()
m =np.random.randint(1, 30, size = (10, 3))
df = pd.DataFrame(m, columns = ["var1", "var2", "var3"])
for i in range(0, len(df)+1):
        for j in range(0, len(df)+1):
            if i-j==3:
                b = df.iloc[j:i]
                for k in range (0,9):
                    a = "erkan_" + str(k+1)
                    globals()["erkan_%s" % (j)] = b
                    print("{0} = {1}". format(a, b))
```

it creates list names as erkan_1, erkan_2, ..., erkan_8
but saves last results. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list and append the result of each iteration in the list like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

m =np.random.randint(1, 30, size = (10, 3))
df = pd.DataFrame(m, columns = ["var1", "var2", "var3"])

dfs = []
for i in range(0, len(df)+1):
    for j in range(0, len(df)+1):
        if i-j==3:
            dfs.append(df.iloc[j:i])
```

`dfs` is the list who has the results of each iteration.

You can also use `pd.concat` to create a unique `DataFrame` from `dfs`:

```
pd.concat(dfs)

Output:
   var1  var2  var3
0     6    10     5
1    16    10    15
2    13     2    17
1    16    10    15
2    13     2    17
3    12    18     9
2    13     2    17
3    12    18     9
4     9    29     1
3    12    18     9
4     9    29     1
5     6    16    22
4     9    29     1
5     6    16    22
6    19     9    23
5     6    16    22
6    19     9    23
7    11    24    14
6    19     9    23
7    11    24    14
8    13     2    26
7    11    24    14
8    13     2    26
9     9    20    21
```

Comment: This is not what I want but thx anyway. I want to save each three rows as as (3x3) matrices. erkan_1, erkan_2, ..., erkan_8